# print dir(XXX) gives out blank attributes

Tags: python, list, xlsx

In short, I work with an xlsx file and while checking some list with `print dir(alist)` get blank attributes.

```
neglist = neglist.tolist()
```

At this point I want to check whether evth is Ok:

```
def check_variab (variab):
    print "The type is %s" % type(variab)
    print "Its length = %i" % len(variab)
    print "Its attributes are:" % dir(variab)

print 'neglist'
check_variab(neglist)
```

But what I get is:

```
type: list
length: 19
attributes:
```

No attributes are printed though the type is list all right, its length and content is ok.

Could anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Your output is *text*, please don't use a screenshot, copy that text and paste it here. In a Windows console, the `[-]` window menu has copy controls you can use here.

Comment: I beg your pardon for my foolishness but what is [-] window menu? Honestly, I tried to find it but failed...

Comment: It's the default window menu present on all Windows windows.

Comment: Also see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ and https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true; looks like the menu changed to one shown when you right-click the menu bar now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use a `%s` placeholder, so *nothing* will be interpolated. Add `%s` or `%r`:

```
print "Its attributes are %s:" % dir(variab)
#                         ^^ A placeholder for the value
```

Without that placeholder, you won't see anything, indeed:

```
>>> variab = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> dir(variab)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
>>> print "Its attributes are:" % dir(variab)
Its attributes are:
>>> print "Its attributes are %s:" % dir(variab)
Its attributes are ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']:
```

You want to use [standard sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) on lists.

Comment: Shame on me! Thanks.